# Construct a map from two equal size arrays

Tags: java

Is there some helper to construct a `Map` from two (equal sized) arrays? That is, some one-line version of something similar to the following:

```
public static <K, V> Map<K, V> createMap(final K[] keys, final V[] values)
{
    assert keys.length == values.length;

    final Map<K, V> map = new HashMap<K, V>();

    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        map.put(keys[i], values[i]);
    }

    return map;
}
```

I have searched [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) as well as Guava's [Maps](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html) without success so far. I was surprised since Guava's ImmutableMap offers nice utility functions like [of()](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html#of%28%29).

Comment: What is the problem with current one ?

Comment: You have to recreate this function every time, whereas ImmutableMap.of() is convenient and right there.

Comment: @sureshatta just guessing: problem with current one is, it is a custom utility method, IOW probably reinventing the wheel, and inconvenient/complex when used in many projects. Or, if putting that for loop as one-liner to every place it's used, it is error-prone copy-paste coding.

Comment: @Micha : Can you add some light on 'have to recreate this function every time' ? I don't get it.

Comment: That code looks perfectly OK for me.

Answer (score 3):

You can try [MapUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections//javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MapUtils.html) from Apache Commons.

MapUtils.putAll(Map, Object[]) should do what you are looking for.

Comment: This uses a multidimensional array, though. The arrays in the question would need to be retrofitted.

Comment: Seems like the array parameter of `putAll()` takes (key, value) pairs instead of `K[] keys` and `V[] values`.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann It actually is `putAll(map,[[keys],[values]])`.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo Please edit his answer, so I can remove this comment and my previous comment.